# GWT / SmartGwt - Updating New Value in SectionStack

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am new to GWT / SmartGWT. I am working on an enhancement on existing application where I have a requirements that, I have to update (display) new value to SectionStack which is entered by user in a textbox.
I am able to display default value when the application loads but can anyone please give me idea how to update value (lable) in the SectionStack in GWt or SmartGWT.

Thanks in Advance.
Jay Shukla

Comment: Not understanding your question. Can you post a sample code?

Comment: SectionStackSection class has setTitle method. You can get SectionStackSection from SectionStack and call setTitle. ??

Comment: Thanks Yusuf. I would like to change value in side the SectionStack.

Comment: Please don't add answers to provide precisions to your question! Instead, click the [edit] button below your question. Please delete all answers that do not aim to actually answer your issue, and instead edit the info in your question.